# Java Recursion Memory

Tags: java, recursion, memory

I am solving problem in codeforces. I program on Java.

In this problem I create array `dp[N][5][3]` of ints (there are about `N*5*3` recursive calls). When `N` is equal to a million, my program falls in memory, however memory limit is about `256 MB`. The same solution in C++ goes well, with eating twice less memory. Why is it so?

Here is the code:

```
    private int MAX = (int) 1E6 + 6;
    private int[] cnt;
    private int[][][] dp;

    private int min(int a, int b) {
        return a > b ? b : a;
    }

    private int max(int a, int b) {
        return a < b ? b : a;
    }

    private int solve(int x, int t1, int t2) {
        // element x,   x used t1 times,   x + 1 used t2 times
        if (dp[x][t1][t2] != -1)
            return dp[x][t1][t2];
        else if (x + 3 > MAX)
            return dp[x][t1][t2] = (cnt[x] - t1) / 3 + (cnt[x + 1] - t2) / 3;

        int ans0, ans1 = 0, ans2 = 0;
        ans0 = (cnt[x] - t1) / 3 + solve(x + 1, t2, 0);
        int min = min(cnt[x] - t1, min(cnt[x + 1] - t2, cnt[x + 2]));
        if (min >= 1)
            ans1 = (cnt[x] - t1 - 1) / 3 + 1 + solve(x + 1, t2 + 1, 1);
        if (min >= 2)
            ans2 = (cnt[x] - t1 - 2) / 3 + 2 + solve(x + 1, t2 + 2, 2);
        return dp[x][t1][t2] = max(ans0, max(ans1, ans2));
    }

    private void solve(InputReader in, PrintWriter out) {
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();

        cnt = new int[MAX];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cnt[in.nextInt()]++;

        dp = new int[MAX][5][3];
        for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                    dp[i][j][k] = -1;

        out.println(solve(1, 0, 0));
    }
```

There is no need for understanding the logic of solve function. Here the recursive method is simply called about `N*5*3` times.

Comment: Can you show how you create those arrays ?

Comment: You can define how much memory Java is allowed to use. Google it.

Comment: Change the heap size in order to allow Java to consume more memory. This can be done via the ide you're using.

Comment: @ArthurAttout here is the link https://codeforces.com/contest/1110/submission/51139125

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need such a large Array (and I recommand you to think twice before using that large array and look for better memory solution) you can increase the max memory size of a java programe at launch time by using the argument `-Xmx`

Eg : `java -jar myProgram.jar -Xmx1G` 
to use 1GB as max heap size memory (note that if its not enough you can increase more)

Note that you can also specify the initial heap size withthe argument `-Xms`

Comment: That is great idea, but this code runs on their servers. Does java use more memory for its data types?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your code. First of all if you work on recursive method jvm stores each object in heap and holds the reference for each object in the stack. If you want to prevent this error you should initialize unused object to null.

Comment: Here is the code https://codeforces.com/contest/1110/submission/51139125